# How to prevent the google chrome to save the session

Tags: google-chrome

While using Google chrome if I shut down it unexpectedly. like turn of pc or terminate the process. it saves all the information. like id password of current accounts. any one can restore and can get the access to the last session. How I can turn off this or stop the chrome to save the informations. Any solution other then incognito mode.

Comment: maybe you can try to run everytime in the incognito mode. Like you can always start chrome with --incognito flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use incognito mode..
https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464&p=cpn_incognito

*Once you exit your guest session, all of your browsing information from the session is completely erased.*

**after comment**
if you really don;t wanna use incognito , then use this app...It stops recording all the browsing history..
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljamgkbcojbnmcaonjokopmcblmmpfch#

Comment: any other solution other then incognito mode.